# Bootstrap 4 list layout for different display

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 what's the best way to display a list that's inline for medium displays and block for smaller devices such as phones. I've currently got something like this, but li items are still inline because of the .list-inline-item

Is this even the best approach? Would it be better to do it purely with flexbox?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="fluid-container">
   <div class="row text-sm-center">
    <ul class="col-md d-md-list-inline d-sm-list-block align-self-center text-md-left" style="background: pink;">
     <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="">About</a>
     </li>
     <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="">Contact</a>
     </li>
     <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="">Charity</a>
     </li>
     <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="">Terms &amp; conditions</a>
     </li>
     <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="">Site map</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-md text-md-right" style="background: green;">
     <p class="m-0">
      &copy; 2011 - 2018 My website, all rights reserved
     </p>
     <p>
      Some other text
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `d-lg-inline-block d-md-block` for list-inline-item ?

Answer (score 1):

In **Bootstrap 4**, the *simplest* way (**no extra CSS**) is to use flexbox to set the direction responsively. Just add `d-flex flex-md-row flex-column` to the row...

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row text-sm-center">
       <ul class="col-md d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-self-center text-md-left" style="background: pink;">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="">Charity</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="">Terms &amp; conditions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="">Site map</a>
                    </li>
       </ul>
       <div class="col-md text-md-right" style="background: green;">
                    <p class="m-0">
                        &copy; 2011 - 2018 My website, all rights reserved
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Some other text
                    </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/KWzGkQEklA

Comment: With the inclusion of flexbox within bootstrap 4, is there much point in using the grid system anymore? I've not used bootstrap for a while and just looking into using it again.

Comment: Sure, the auto layout columns are still considered part of [the "grid"](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). You may also want to use the classic grid to set widths.

Answer (score 0):

I use flex, it is quick, easy and reliable. when using flex:0; make sure to provide a flex-basis:auto; specifically for ie11:

scss:

```
ul.class-name
{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;

  li.class-name
  {
     /* fallback for ie11 */
     flex-basis: auto;

     /* hide from ie11 with @supports because it doesn't understand this */
     @supports(display: grid)
     {
       flex:0;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Bootstrap 4 what's the best way to display a list that's inline for
>   medium displays and block for smaller devices such as phones

Use `d-*` classes - [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/)

inline for medium and up use `d-md-inline`

for block below medium viewports amd inline from md use combination like `d-block d-md-inline`